# Classic asp: Function call by reference doesn't work with an array

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, byref, pass-by-reference

I have an array witch I pass to a function by reference to sort it. However, seems like the array is passed byval. Can anyone solve what's the problem? (Also sort workarounds accepted)

---

1) The script below passes an array by-reference to the sort function.

2) Sort function outputs the sorted array values.

3) The script outputs the sorted array values. However they are not sorted.

---

The script outputs:

300,200,100,,

100,200,300,

---

```
'declare variables
mitta(1) = 1
mitta(2) = 2
mitta(3) = 3

sort(mitta)  ' see the function below

' show variables
For i = 1 To 3
    response.write mitta(i) & ","
next

' sort function
function sort(byref a)
    dim num,i,j,temp
    num = ubound(a)+1
    For i = 0 To num - 1
       For j = i + 1 To num - 1
          If a(i) < a(j) Then
             temp = a(i)
             a(i) = a(j)
             a(j) = temp
          End If
       Next
    Next

    ' show sorted variables
    For i = 0 To num - 1
        response.write a(i) & ","
        a(i) = 0
    next
end function
```

Comment: How do you know it's not based on your samples? It's already sorted. Also you don't need the variable num. Since you're adding 1 to `ubound(a)` and then using num - 1 it makes sense just to use `ubound(a)`.  Also, you're probably getting dumped from your function in the last iteration of the j loop. When i = `num - 1` (the end of the array), j will attempt to be `i + 1`. This is out of the bounds of the array and `a(i) < a(j)` will fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By wrapping `mitta` in parentheses in the function call `sort(mitta)`, you're actually passing it by value, despite the function declaration.  From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx:

> The rules are
>
> 3.1) An argument list for a function call with an assignment to the
>   returned value must be surrounded by
>   parens: Result = MyFunc(MyArg)
>   3.2) An argument list for a subroutine call (or a function call with no
>   assignment) that uses the Call keyword
>   must be surrounded by parens: Call
>   MySub(MyArg)
>   3.3) If 3.1 and 3.2 do not apply then the list must NOT be surrounded by
>   parens.
>
> And finally there is the byref rule:
>   arguments are passed byref when
>   possible but if there are “extra”
>   parens around a variable then the
>   variable is passed byval, not byref.
>
> Now it should be clear why the
>   statement MySub(MyArg) is legal but
>   MyOtherSub(MyArg1, MyArg2) is not. The
>   first case appears to be a subroutine
>   call with parens around the argument
>   list, but that would violate rule 3.3.
>   Then why is it legal? In fact it is **a
>   subroutine call with no parens around
>   the arg list, but parens around the
>   first argument!** This passes the
>   argument by value. The second case is
>   a clear violation of rule 3.3, and
>   there is no way to make it legal, so
>   we give an error.

See also the MSDN reference for [ByRef and ByVal Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Instead, you should call `sort` either with:

```
sort mitta
```

or:

```
Call sort(mitta)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
call sort(mitta)
```

That's it, just add the keyword `call`. Complete reference [is available here](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-specify-byref/byval-in-vbscript.html).

BTW, your code has problems. The arrays are 0 based.

Comment: If he's passing the array in as a reference, he shouldn't have to return anything.

Comment: @Joel: I've revised my answer. VBScript does not seem to respect ByVal/ByRef. It forces ByVal for "normal" variables and ByRef for objects.

Comment: That "complete reference" link is not really suitable for classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an `object` as parameter, you are passing a **`pointer`** to the `object`, not the `object` itself (this apply to all languages I know). So it does not matter if you pass it `ByVal` or `ByRef`, because by definition you are always passing a `pointer` (a reference to the object)